How can I purchase as many types of products as possible within given budget (closest to given budget)
Situation:
You are given a list of products sold in the store, and you want to purchase as many types of products as possible within your given budget (closest to given budget). Write function "maximize products(budget, product_list)" that takes a budget and a product list as input and returns a list of as many products that can be purchased as possible. The returned list should contain only the names of the products you are purchasing, and you should include as many varieties as possible without exceeding your budget.
Example Input:
budget = 3000, product_list = [("Apples", 1000), ("Banana", 500), ("Oranges", 1500), ("Grapes", 2000), ("Cherry", 800)]
Example Output:
["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"]
I was able to include as many varieties as possible, but I am having trouble getting combination of products that costs closest to given budget. Please help...
def maximize_products(budget, product_list):

    sorted_products = sorted(product_list, key=lambda x: x[1])

    selected_products = []
    total_cost = 0

    for product, price in sorted_products:
        if total_cost + price <= budget:
            total_cost += price
            selected_products.append(product)
        else:
            break

    return selected_products

budget=int(input("budget: "))
product_list=[]
n = int(input("number of products: "))

for i in range(n):
    name, price=input("Enter the product name and price (ex: apple 1000): ").split()
    product_list.append((name, int(price)))


print(maximize_products(budget, product_list))

how can I add function that calculate and compare the sum of product prices??

It is a DP problem
you should make dp array of dp[apple][bannana][orange][grape][cherry] or something and solve as
dp[next] = max(dp[apple+1], dp[banana+1],....)
or something

When I asked chatgpt, it recommended using DP, but I haven't learned DP, so I was wondering if the problem could be solved using for loop. But still thanks for reply.

If you're using combinations of fruits and spending considerable time to cover all cases, and comparing until your combination exceeds the budget, then maybe yes.

It's unclear which of "as many types of products as possible" and "closest to given budget" is the real goal.

This is a Knapsack problem (Consider profit of each item to be equal, say 1), a search will give you algorithms that you can use to solve this.

"as many types of products as possible" is priority, and among the combinations that satisfies it, the combination closest to given budget is the answer.

It's a 0/1 knapsack problem which can be solved using dynamic programming.
Solution Explanation

1. Initialize variables: Create a 2D array dp of size (n+1) x (budget+1), where n is the number of products in the list. Each position dp[i][j] represents the maximum total cost that can be achieved using the first i products and a budget of j.

2. To build the DP table: Iterate over each product and each possible budget from 1 to the given budget. For each product i and budget j, there are two choices:

Include the current product if its price is less than or equal to the current budget. In this case, the maximum total cost is the maximum of two options:

Excluding the current product (dp[i-1][j]), or
Including the current product and reducing the budget by the price of the current product (dp[i-1][j - product_list[i-1][1]] + product_list[i-1][1]).


Exclude the current product if its price exceeds the current budget. In this case, the maximum total cost remains the same as the previous row (dp[i-1][j]).


3. Find the combination of products: Backtrack from the last cell of the table to reconstruct the combination of products that led to the maximum total cost. Start from the last cell (dp[n][budget]) and move backward. If the value of dp[i][j] is different from dp[i-1][j], it means that the i-th product was included in the combination. Add the name of the product to the combination list and update j to j - product_list[i-1][1]. Continue the process until reaching the first product.


Solution
def maximize_products(budget, product_list):
    # Initialize variables
    n = len(product_list)
    dp = [[0] * (budget + 1) for _ in range(n + 1)]

    # Build DP table
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(1, budget + 1):
            if product_list[i - 1][1] <= j:
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i - 1][j - product_list[i - 1][1]] + product_list[i - 1][1])
            else:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j]

    # Find the combination of products
    combination = []
    j = budget
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        if dp[i][j] != dp[i - 1][j]:
            combination.append(product_list[i - 1][0])
            j -= product_list[i - 1][1]

    return combination[::-1]

